# Difficulty selecting data from multiple tables with a sub-query

Tags: mysql

Afternoon,

Below is a relational schema I have created to assist in answering my question.

```
JOBS (**jobClass**, Description, chargePerHour)

EMPLOYEES (**empNo**, *jobClass*, firstName, lastName)
```

Foreign Key **jobClass** references **JOBS**

```
PROJECTS (**projectNo**, projectName)

PROJECTS2EMPLOYEES (**projEmpKey**, *projectNo*, *empNo*, hoursBilled, projectLeader)
```

Foreign Key **projectNo** references **PROJECTS**
Foreign Key **empNo** references **EMPLOYEES**

```
Bold = PK (Primary Key)
Italic = FK (Foreign Key)
```

I am trying to select projectName from the Projects table and the full name of the project leader for each project from the Employees table.

Project leaders are differentiated by a 1 in the projectLeader field in the projects2employees tables.

My last attempt was

```
SELECT projectName, CONCAT_WS(" ", firstName, lastName) FROM Projects, Employees WHERE projectNo IN
(SELECT projectNo from projects2employees WHERE projectLeader = 1)
```

but it didn't work out very well.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` with an `ON` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT p.projectName, CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName)
  FROM Projects p
  JOIN projects2employees pe
    ON (p.projectNo = pe.projectNo and pe.projectLeader = 1)
  JOIN employees e
    ON (pe.empno= e.empno)
```

Comment: I attempted this but it returned an empty set.

Comment: That works perfectly but I'm having difficulty understanding HOW it works. would you be able to help me understand? Specifically, I don't understand the use of the single letters in front of some of the field names.

Comment: These are aliases. A way to "give a table a nickname" , used for convenience issues (shorter) and to avoid ambigiously column names(same column name, different tables.. which one to use?)

Comment: Would you be able to give me the same query without the aliases so I can better understand how they work?

Comment: You have to eithet use alias here or the table name before the column since you have common column names . What would `empno =empno` mean if you didn't have alias before?

Comment: Ah, okay. I understand.